# how can I support HTTP 1.1 keep-alive in twisted.web.server

Tags: python, http, twisted, keep-alive

I have a twisted server that uses twisted.web.server to listen to HTTP requests. I am looking for documentation on how to allow my server to support HTTP 1.1 keep-alive.

Thanks!

Comment: all http 1.1 connections are persistent unless `Connection: close` is specified.

Answer (score 3):

Twisted Web servers are HTTP/1.1 and they treat connections as persistent by default (as any HTTP/1.1 server must do).